# MySQL: How to speed up archive table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an archive table in which only the changes to a record are stored with a validity date. An example would be a price archive for products.

And if you now want to select the status at a given date, I have the following SELECT.
The problem is that this gets slower and slower the more changes there are, because in the first step the database first reads all records and then in the next step appends those that have a greater validity date. In the end, only the ones with the largest validity date remain on the far left.

Is there any way to make this more effective?

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 
   ON d1.id = d2.id AND 
      d1.valid_from_date < d2.valid_from_date
WHERE 
   d2.id IS NULL AND 
   d1.valid_from_date <= '2023-01-01';

CREATE TABLE data (
    id int,
    valid_from_date DATE,
    foo varchar(255),
    bar varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, valid_from_date)
);
```

Comment: Have you relevant indexes? Please show tables structure

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question. We need a bunch more information to help you.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev id and valid_from together is the primary key.  The SELECT speed is fast enough with for example 10.000 rows @ 0.0048 seconds. But if I double the rows, the SELECT gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this index on the date and id columns.

```
CREATE INDEX x_valid_from_date_id ON data(valid_from_date, id);
```

**EDIT** According to your comment you already have an index (your PK) on `(id, valid_from_date)`.

**EDIT** If you're looking for the latest row for each `id` on or before a particular date, this query might help.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM data a
  JOIN (  
       SELECT id, MAX(valid_from_date) valid_from_date
         FROM data
        WHERE valid_from_date <= '2023-01-01'
        GROUP BY id
  ) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.valid_from_date = b.valid_from_date
```

The subquery gets the date you want for every id, then the JOIN retrieves the details. The MariaDB / MySQL query planner is quite clever about MAX ... GROUP BY queries given appropriate indexes.

Read Markus Winand's [excellent ebook](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) to learn a lot more about this topic.

Comment: I tried this and it is a factor of 50 slower (0.047 vs 0.0009 seconds) on 40,000 test records.
When I look at the execution with EXPLAIN, the whole table is run twice. With mine, only once.

But I don't know yet how this behaves when the table grows. If the access time remains stable then it would be beneficial.

Comment: I can't understand why this is so slow. The subselect with the GROUP BY takes only 0.0005 seconds and does most of the work. EXPLAIN also shows me only one SIMPLE select type. But if I then execute the complete statement, it becomes three steps and the first one says "<derived2>" as table and the possible_keys = NULL, extra is "where".

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `NOT EXISTS` instead `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT NULL` condition like:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM data d1
WHERE 
   d1.valid_from_date <= '2023-01-01' AND
   NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM data d2 
     WHERE d1.id = d2.id AND 
        d1.valid_from_date < d2.valid_from_date
   );
```

Comment: 'ang on 'ang on. The original questioner is doing a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` antijoin operation. Switching to ordinary inner `JOIN` isn't quite right.

Comment: Sorry, @O.Jones, my bad. edited

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Thanks! I tried this and let the table grow. While there were more and more changed entries, the total number of current data remained nearly the same. There were about 57000 entries in the table and the three SELECTs returned about 11,000 of them.

Your query took 0.0011 seconds. In my original SELECT it is 0.0010 seconds and in the other example of O.Jones the time increased more significantly to 0.089 seconds.

Could it be that the advantage of "NOT EXISTS" comes out later?